# update sass user defined color variables

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have created an angular **component** `MyComponent` that has a **sass** and the **theme** file.

**mycomponent.component.scss**

```
@import "../styles/common";
@import 'mycomponent.theme';

.element {
  color:$primary
}
```

in the **common.scss**, I have imported other files likes **variables.scss** that contain `$primary` with predefined or default colour and other theme variables.

and in the **mycomponent.theme.scss**, I defined the `@mixin` to update the primary variable

```
@mixin mycomponent-theme() {
    $primary: green ;
}
```

Now the **theme** file that creates the final **theme.css** call this `@mixin`

```
@include mycomponent-theme();
```

but the `element` class's `color` is not getting updated to the green color as mixin is updating the `$primary` variable.

Am I making any mistake? Or what is the other way to achieve this?

**Update** 
Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/ermarkar/pen/wygwYp?page=1&

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has to do with scoping.

The `$primary` variable that you set to the value `green` in the mixin `mycomponent-theme()` is a **local variable**, therefore, it is only visible to the code that is inside that mixin.

Even though it has the same name as another **global variable** (I assume it is global), they are different variables.

When you wrote:

```
.element {
  color:$primary
}
```

Sass used the **global variable** called `$primary`, whose value your mixin did not change, the mixin created a **local variable** with the same name.

There is a [very good resource](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498) that I recommend you to read that helps understand variable scoping in Sass, much better than I can explain here.

**UPDATE:**

One thing you could do that I just thought of, is use `!global`. This keyword lets you manipulate variables in the global scope from within function or mixin blocks.

In your case, if you change your mixin to this:

```
@mixin mycomponent-theme() {
    $primary: green !global;
}
```

Then the `mycomponent-theme()` mixin will change the global `$primary` variable.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Could you perhaps create a CodePen demo with all the code that you are running?

Comment: It does not work in your CodePen demo because you call your mixin after you used the variable. At the time your code gets to `color: $primary`, the value of the `$primary` variable is still `blue`. Only after that do you change it's value to `green`.

Comment: then how can I solve this? In actual component is a library and the theme.scss file will be part of the consumer app that will use the mixin from exported scss from library.